# Pass an expression to an org babel code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Consider the followig python code block

```
#+name: whatever
#+header: :var x="2*np.pi"
#+BEGIN_SRC python
import numpy as np
1+x
#+END_SRC
# .
```

The code will break, because x is passed to the interpreter as a string and then added together with an integer which is not legal (the trick would work in Maxima for some reason, though). If I remove the quotes ("), then Org complains that it can't find a reference (or, something such). So, how to insert an expression such as `2*np.pi` to a code block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can use a language expression as the value to a `:var`, the [doc](http://orgmode.org/manual/var.html#var) says:

> Arguments can take values as literals, or as references, or even as
>   Emacs Lisp code

A possible way to achieve this is to use another code block to compute the expression, then use it as the value to the `:var`:

> "code block with arguments"
>
> ```
>  a 'src' code block name, as assigned by '#+NAME:', followed by
>  parentheses and optional arguments passed within the parentheses
>  following the `src' code block name using standard function call
>  syntax
> ```

You example could then be:

```
#+name: twotimesnppi
#+BEGIN_SRC python
import numpy as np
return 2*np.pi
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: twotimesnppi
: 6.28318530718

#+name: whatever2
#+header: :var x=twotimesnppi()
#+BEGIN_SRC python
return 1+x
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: whatever2
: 7.28318530718
```

Comment: That solution seemed like an overkill so i went for an uglier, but shorter one: eval. Since x ends up being a string, eval(x) is going to give the desired result in case of Python.